# How can I make a DIV cursor and background color change if I hover over it?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="authTabs">
   <div class="h2">Login</div>
   <div class="h2">Register</div>
</div>
```

I am using CSS. Can someone tell me how I can make it so that 
my cursor changes to a finger pointing and my background 
color changes when the Login or Register DIVs are hovered over?

Comment: Whose background color do you want to change?

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS right now. you can use jquery to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj95k/)

```
.authTabs {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.h2:hover {
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css definitions:

```
.h2:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.h2{
  backgorund-color : black;
cursor: pointer
}
.h2:hover{
  backgorund-color : blue;
cursor: pointer
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.clsName:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red; // required color
}

.authTabs div:nth-of-type(1)
{
 cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red; // required color
} 

.authTabs div:nth-of-type(1)
{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red; // required color
}
```

Comment: This seems awefully complicated for what OP wants to accomplish. Why the nth-of-type?

Comment: What if he wants to add different color to login and pwd?? i dint change his html

Comment: In that case he probably should give them a different id, and color them using the id.

Comment: That's why i specified like this. Any problems??

Answer (score 0):

```
h2:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is for `<h2>` elements, not `class="h2"`.

Comment: It's a div element, not a h2 element.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't read too carefully. I thought OP had h2-elements and not div-elements with classes named h2. However the CSS selector is not the most important part of the answer but rather the attributes OP is asking for.